# WSO2 multi-tenancy with Apache ActiveMQ

Tags: wso2, activemq-classic, wso2-message-broker, wso2-esb

Our proposed deployment for WSO2 is to have a single WSO2 instance(JVM) and support multiple tenants within it. This has worked cleanly for us. Now, we need to extend this model to Apache ActiveMQ also.

i.e. we want tenant level isolation with Apache ActiveMQ also. In other words, the queue meant for tenant 1 should not be accessed by other tenants. In this respect, I had a couple of questions

1. Is there a way to support multi-tenants within a single Apache ActiveMQ
   installation? If so, how do we align a WSO2 tenant with the
   corresponding tenant in Apache ActiveMQ ?
2. If the above option is not available, then we are okay to have a separate Apache ActiveMQ for each tenant. In this case, how do we configure multiple Apache ActiveMQs with a single WSO2 installation ?

Any other pointers are truly appreciated !

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. This is possible with Virtual hosts [1] configured on Apache ActiveMQ. 
   Each virtual host is isolated, there by supporting multi-tenant like behavior.
2. At the moment it is not possible to configure multiple Apache ActiveMQ's or Multiple virtual hosts with a single WSO2 Server instance.

[1] https://activemq.apache.org/apollo/documentation/user-manual.html#Virtual_Hosts